# TFS WorkItem Proxy

Tags: workitem

Any one try to develop proxy for TFS work items? 
Current TFS Proxy supports only for Source control not for TFS WorkItems.

If I want to Implement TFS WorkItem what I have to do? All Ideas are welcome :)

-Murali

Comment: Since my TFS server is too far from part of developer environment, we are already using TFS Proxy for source control., so we will get files very faster. But for workitems we are still depending on main server. We are having our own WorkItem board to show the current status of the project. which take some time to load and do some operation due to dependency of Main server. more over I am not able to see any option in visual studio for workitem functionality. Do you have any guide / url to help me?

Comment: @rene 
one reason you'd want to cache workitems & other artefacts, if for the remote developer on low bandwidth connections. the dev checks out the code & gets related items with it and goes offline. a very common scenario around where i work, but tfs proxy doesn't do that :(

Answer (score 0):

Team Companion supports offline editing of existing work items which might help you to some degree.

You sync with the server, go offline, do your stuff and at the end of the day go online and  sync with the server again.